# ios time to int minutes

Tags: ios

I have an `NSString` with the value `@"1:10:39"`

What's the fastest / most convenient way to convert this time to minutes? eg. `70.65`

I'm not asking for a hand out here, show code only if you feel comfortable doing so. I'm mainly looking for a recommendation. *Thanks*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
NSString *zeroString = @"00:00:00";
NSString *timeString = @"1:10:39";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *zeroDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:zeroString];
NSDate *offsetDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeString];
NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [offsetDate timeIntervalSinceDate:zeroDate];
CGFloat minutes = (timeDifference/60);
NSLog(@"%0.2fmins",minutes);
```

Comment: +1 to all as all are good and usable. However, I've never calculated time this way so it gets the prize. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `NSString`'s `componentsSeparatedByString` to get an array containing the strings '1', '10' and '39' in that order, then pull the values from that array and perform `integerValue` on them to convert to a number, and do the necessary arithmetic on those, being sure to check I got exactly three things in the array as a validation step and to avoid exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *timeString = @"1:10:39";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm:ss";
NSDate *timeDate = [formatter dateFromString:timeString];

formatter.dateFormat = @"hh";
int hours = [[formatter stringFromDate:timeDate] intValue];
formatter.dateFormat = @"mm";
int minutes = [[formatter stringFromDate:timeDate] intValue];
formatter.dateFormat = @"ss";
int seconds = [[formatter stringFromDate:timeDate] intValue];

float timeInMinutes = hours * 60 + minutes + seconds / 60.0;
```